# Bittrex REST API v3, Python POST orders, INVALID_CONTENT_HASH

Tags: python-2.7, request, python-requests, http-post, bitcoin

I would like to create orders with bittrex Rest API v3 to use my bittrex credit.

I can't create a valid CONTENT_HASH, so I can't create the order. can someone help me, the code is below.

API documentation: https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#/definitions/NewOrder

```
import urllib2;import random;import httplib;import urllib;import json;import hashlib;import 
hmac;import time
import requests
import json
import base64
import hashlib
import time
import hmac
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

def NewOrder(market, amount, price):
market = 'BTC-'+market
uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders'

payload = {
    'marketSymbol': market,
    'direction': 'BUY',
    'type': 'LIMIT',
    'quantity': amount,
    #'ceiling': amount, #0.0, #'number (double)',
    'limit': price,
    'timeInForce': 'GOOD_TILL_CANCELLED',#'POST_ONLY_GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    #'clientOrderId': accountId,
    'useAwards': True
}
#ceiling (optional, must be included for ceiling orders and excluded for non-ceiling orders)
#clientOrderId (optional) client-provided identifier for advanced order tracking

timestamp = str(int(time.time()*1000))
Content = json.dumps(payload, separators=(',',':'))
#Content = '{"direction":"BUY","limit":0.00021,"marketSymbol":"BTC-HEDG","quantity":1.1,"useAwards":true,"timeInForce":"GOOD_TILL_CANCELLED","type":"LIMIT"}'
#Content = '{"direction":"BUY","marketSymbol":"BTC-HEDG","useAwards":true,"timeInForce":"GOOD_TILL_CANCELLED","limit":0.00021,"type":"LIMIT","quantity":1.1}'
print Content
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(Content.encode()).hexdigest()
print '---', contentHash

Method = 'POST'
PreSign = timestamp + uri + Method + contentHash# + accountId
Signature = hmac.new(apisecret, PreSign.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
      'Api-Key' : apikey,
      'Api-Timestamp' : timestamp,
      'Api-Content-Hash': contentHash,
      'Api-Signature' : Signature
}
r = requests.post(uri, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=11)
print(r.json())

>>> NewOrder('HEDG', 1.1, 0.00021)

{u'code': u'INVALID_CONTENT_HASH'}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check the spelling of the `timeInForce` to `GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED`. Notice that Bittrex misspelled the word "till".

Answer (score -1):

For fixing the INVALID_CONTENT_HASH error this did it for me:

```
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(bytes(json.dumps(payload), "utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score -1):

You're only using the URI, although the API requires you to use the URI + query string. Change:

```
url = uri + '?' + '&'.join(['{}={}'.format(k, v) for (k, v) in payload.items()])
PreSign = timestamp + url + Method + contentHash + accountId

...

r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=11)
```

NOTE: It only works if you send the params using the `json` arg. I tried sending the params using the `params` and `data` args and got the same INVALID_CONTENT_HASH result.